# Change url to "seo-url"

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, seo, url-rewriting

i created this url for any detail-site:

```
http://example.com/detail.php?id=product-name
```

My php :

```
if(htmlspecialchars($_GET["id"]) != '') {
    $product_name = htmlspecialchars($_GET["id"]);
    $product_name = basename($product_name);
```

For SEO i wanted to change this url to:

```
http://example.com/detail/product-name
```

But how to work with php in this case?
I cant work with index.php etc..

Any idea´s ? :)

EDIT :

Now i have this file structure for a detail page:

```
http://example.com/dir/detail/index.php
```

So which url shall i call to get to:

```
http://example.com/dir/detail/product_name_1
```

?? could u refer to this maybe? Greetings!

EDIT 2:

ok i changed it to:

```
RewriteRule dir/detail/^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ dir/detail/index.php?id=$1
```

But url still is not created, why?

Answer (score 0):

Put this htaccess file in the directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ detail.php?id=$1
```

So now whenever you have `detail.php?id=hello-world` you can write it as follow: `detail/hello-world`

You can access the `id` in the same way as well. `$_GET['id']`

Comment: thanks for answer, i edited my question:) could you refer to it maybe? thanks:)